# Big O notation (Order of convergence)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

What is the order of Convergence (Big $\mathcal{O}$) of this function:
$f(x) = 1+(\frac{1}{x})^x$ ?
I have tried the same approach to find the order of convergence of the inverse function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and the function $\alpha_{n} =\frac{n+1}{n^{2}}$, but it doesn't seem like a good way to do it.

Comment: 1/ There is no $x$ in your definition of $f(x)$. 2/ Even if you replace $n$ with $x$, since this has a limit when $n\to+\infty$, you will get an $O(1)$ (as $x\to+\infty$), but it's also an $O(x)$ or any $O(g(x))$ for $g$ asymptotically larger than a constant (i.e. unbouned). 3/ You must say where you are looking for the asymptotic behaviour: I assume it's for $x\to+\infty$, but it could be $x\to a$ for a given real $a$, for instance.

Comment: I have edited the formula in the question

Comment: And $x\to+\infty$? Not that it changes much the answer, but we have to know where to look.

Comment: I am sorry, yes it is like that.

Comment: Ok, then prove $f$ has a limit and you are done.

Comment: What approach have you tried and what type of answer are you looking for? For instance, $f(x)\in \mathcal O(1+\left (\frac{1}{x}\right)^x)$, (trivially $f(x)\in \mathcal O(f(x))$ always), but this is unlikely to be a satisfying answer.

Comment: Oh, so is it $\mathcal{O}(1)$ ? Sorry but I am still a high school student and this seems a bit difficult.

Comment: $f=O(g)$ as $x\to +\infty$ if there is are real numbers $M$ and $x_m$ such that $|f(x)|<Mg(x)$ for $x>x_m$. If $f$ has a limit $L$ as $x\to+\infty$, then take $g\equiv1$ and any $M>L$ will do, for a large enough $x_m$. That is, if $f$ has a limit, then $f=O(1)$ (if that limit is zero, we might be able to find a tighter bound, but it doesn't matter, and here the limit is nonzero anyway).

Comment: Note also that if $f=O(g)$, then $f=O(h)$ for any function $h$ that grows faster than $g$ (i.e. if $h/g\to+\infty$). The big-$O$ only guarantees $f$ is bounded *above*, it's not necessarily the tightest bound possible, and it says nothing about a bound *below* (see the $\Theta$ notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) for a more restrictive definition).